# Can't bind to 'routerLink'/'ngClass since it isn't a known property of 'a', eventhough they are imported

Tags: angular, typescript, compiler-errors, migration

I migrated an old angular project from angular 7 to 16.
When I try to run the app, I get huge amount of errors, which are mostly:
Can't bind to 'ngClass' since it isn't a known property of 'a'
Can't bind to 'routerLink' since it isn't a known property of 'a'

This shouldn't be happening since, I imported the RouterModule and the CommonModule in the main module of the application and every child module, where they are necessary.
If we look at one specific case, the resource-management-list-page.component.html: There we have

`<a   [routerLink]="'/environment/resource-management/operating-equipments'" [ngClass]="{ active: tab == 'operating-equipments' }">` 
Here i get the errors shown above.

In the module: ResourceManagementModule, which exports the ResourceManagementListPageComponent, the following modules are imported

```
import { RouterModule } from "@angular/router";
import { CommonModule } from "@angular/common";
...
@NgModule({...
imports: \[

        CommonModule,
        RouterModule,
        ...
        ]
    ...
```

The same is true for our site.module.ts, which is our main module (works like app.module.ts).

The whole error message looks like this:

```
Error: src/app/modules/resourcemanagement/pages/resource-management-list-page/resource-management-list-page.component.html:25:11 - error NG8002: Can't bind to 'routerLink' since it isn't a known property of 'a'.

25           \[routerLink\]="'/environment/resource-management/operating-equipments'"


src/app/modules/resourcemanagement/pages/resource-management-list-page/resource-management-list-page.component.ts:15:16
15   templateUrl: "./resource-management-list-page.component.html",

Error occurs in the template of component ResourceManagementListPageComponent.
```

I have no idea how to fix this or what is wrong, help would be appreciated.
More context can be given if necessary.

Update: For the migration, I followed the https://update.angular.io/?v=7.2-16.0 guide. Some steps were skipped, if the mentioned changed components, were not used by our application.

Comment: Have you tried to import the BrowserModule ?

Comment: Yes, the import { BrowserModule } from "@angular/platform-browser"; is also in the site and the ResourceManagementModule. This is also declared in the ngModule annotation. Thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

First, have you tried using the Angular update guide?  I'd suggest starting there if you haven't already: https://update.angular.io/?v=7.0-16.0

For the `routerLink` issue, there should be no reason to bind with the bracket syntax and then pass in a double-quoted string.  If that value is hard coded you can simplify that.

```html
<a routerLink="/environment/resource-management/operating-equipments">
```

for the `ngClass` issue, according to [the docs](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass) it looks like you need have the class name in quotes, like this:

```html
<a [ngClass]="{ 'active': tab == 'operating-equipments' }">
```

Comment: 1. I used the guide and forgot to mention it. I updated my question. 2. This seems to have worked. The error I got was 'Can't bind to 'routerLink' since it isn't a known property of 'a' ', so I thought routerLink wasn't known to the <a> class. Thank you. 3. This didn't change anything. I had to disable my prettier plugin, to allow these single quotes around active.